# How to extract value from serialized json response in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am getting a response in form of serialized json format for an api request as below

```json
{"Data":"{\"orderId\":null,\"Tokens\":{\"Key\":\"abcdefgh123456\",\"Txnid\":\"test_5950\"}","success":true,"Test":"success"}
```

I want to extract Key value in Jmeter and I have to use into next request. Can someone help me on extracting the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JSON really looks exactly like you posted the most suitable Post-Processor would be [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

The relevant regular expression would be something like:

```
"Key"?\s*:?\s*"(\w+)"
```

where:

- ``?\s*` - arbitrary number of whitespaces (just in case)
- `\w` - matches "word" character (alphanumeric plus underscores)
- `+` - repetition
- `()` - grouping

[image]

More information:

- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)
- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. but will it work for the serialized json?. the exact json format is updated in the question. earlier I posted the response without Code snippet selection. sorry for that.

Comment: It's not "serialized", it's "escaped", in that case you will need to update the regular expression to something like `\\"Key\\"?\s*:?\s*\\"(\w+)\\"`. I don't know whether it's a copy-paste issue or the "serialized" JSON in `Data` section is really invalid, if it's valid - you can use 2 JSON [JMESPath Extractors](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide/), the first to get `Data` section, and the second to get `Token.Key` from the Data JMeter Variable

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON seems incorrect. The valid JSON should be like:

```
{
   "Data":{
      "orderId":null,
      "Tokens":{
         "Key":"abcdefgh123456",
         "Txnid":"test_5950"
      },
      "success":true,
      "Test":"success"
   }
}
```

- Add a [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) to the request from where you want to extract the Key value.
- assign a variable name, i.e `key`
- JSON Path Expression will be : `.Data.Tokens.Key`
- use the extracted value as `${key}` into the next request.

Comment: Thank you for the reply ...but my json is in serialized form. I updated the exact json in the question. earlier I posted the response without Code snippet selection. sorry for that.

Comment: In that case, you have to use a regular expression extractor and put the regular expression as `\\"Key\\"?\s*:?\s*\\"(\w+)\\"` . You can also test it here at https://regex101.com/